# HTML include code from another file (via templating engine?)

Tags: html, ejs

Searching for an option to split html to parts, so that I could include them on the run. Thought I could use EJS for it. For example I want to be able to write something like this:

```
<div class="row>
  <% include forms/login_form %>
</div>
```

where all the html markup code for login form is taken out from main html file and put into **forms/login_form.ejs** file.

This doesn't work, unfortunately.

Is it possible to use EJS (or any other templating engine) to achieve this?

Note: this is pure client-side code, no node.js or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. jQuery [template plugin](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template#jqueryloadtemplate).
2. Client Templating [with jQuery](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Oct/13/Client-Templating-with-jQuery)